# Customize Smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I want to customize the following diagram:

[image]

With following code

```
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
 \begin{document}
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {XYZ,LOREM IPSUM},
    }
 \end{document}
```

to be like

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package does accept rotate and so on options, but the orientation of this diagram is entirely due to the node anchors. It is straightforward to modify them.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begingroup%make modifications local
\tikzset{description title/.append style={anchor=west},
 description/.append style={anchor=east},
 every shadow/.append style={shadow xshift=-0.5ex}}
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {XYZ,LOREM IPSUM},
    }\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems it is Tikz-based but the package do not accept `rotate` or `xscale=-1` keys as an option.

I succeed it with `\reflectbox{}`.

```
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}

 \begin{document}
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {XYZ,LOREM IPSUM},
    }

    \reflectbox{\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {\reflectbox{XYZ},\reflectbox{LOREM IPSUM}},
    }}
 \end{document}
```

Output :
[image]